# Preloading images in Lottie / Bodymovin

Tags: jquery, preload, lottie

Is it possible to display progress of multiple images being loaded in Lottie animation.

> e.g 1/10, 2/10, 3/10 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible, you can include multiple images inside of .json or you can add image folder and then you can request from the folder. as you wish. I wrote content for this. [How to work image sequence in Lottie](https://medium.com/@aydinuzmez/how-to-make-image-sequences-with-lottie-in-android-easy-66af61c221ea).

shortly;

```
> Open the Bodymovin in After effects
> Click setting of the composition that has been made an animation.
 > but if you use a website. you can export a demo HTML for javascript
> Click Assets → Include in json
> Set to destination
> And Click the render button
> export data.json
```